# How does blender achieve seamless noise textures for cubes?

Tags: texturing, displacement, texture-coordinates

When using generated noise textures (i.e. "Noise", "Magic", "Voronoi", ...) for the displacement modifier or as surface for a cube there are no seams visible.

See my gif for ants for demonstration (Cube with Voronoi Texture):

[image]

How does blender achieve this? Does it sample the noise texture on a sphere and projects it onto the object like proposed here (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97591/how-to-create-a-seamless-cubemap-noise-texture)?

**Edit**: Thank you @moonboots and @crantisz - now i got it :) The word texture was always connected with 2D in my brain and did not match with 3D at first ;) So in other words: The space itself around the object is filled with a 3D - Voronoi field / pattern (see example one below) and you can see the intersection between the object boundary with this 3D pattern on the objects surface. [image: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337958447/figure/fig2/AS:836955407413249@1576557127370/An-example-of-using-3D-Voronoi-diagram-based-on-hyperuniform-points-cloud.jpg]

Comment: these are 3D textures, that's why they are seamless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As moonboots has commented, this is 3D texture. In fact, you can specify the type of it from 1D to 4D texture:

[image]

But what it is basically means? It's easy to understand, then you set randomness to 0. In this case, Voronoi's anchors is set into regular grid:

[image]

But what is interesting if we start to extrude this plane. We will actually see what next layer will reveal on top of current one:

[image]

Now you can see that the Voronoi's anchors is located not in 2D, but in 3D space.

When slowly get back randomness back to 100, and you will see how Voronoi texture actually build.

[image]

In different situations, 2D type or 4D type of Voronoi may help. 2D produces flat dots, so the size of shapes is more even. 4D texture can be used to shift texture in additional dimension, so you can get different 3D textures and smooth transition between them.